# TRIM() Function With Linked Server

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, trim

I have a linked server connection for a `postgresql` into `sql server`.  I can run this in Sql Server  `Select * from OpenQuery(LinkedServer,'Select * from alphadawg')` and this returns all results, but the second I try to add in any functions I start getting errors.  For example, if I wanted to `TRIM()` the trailing spaces off of a field

```
Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
              'Select TRIM(trailing ' ' from ad.userid) As "User ID"
              FROM alphadawg ad')
```

I get an error of

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ' from ad.userid) As "User ID"

Okay, so maybe the issue is I am trying to execute postgresql in Sql Server, so I altered the syntax to

```
    Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
              'Select RTRIM(ad.userid) As "User ID"
              FROM alphadawg ad')
```

But that then threw an error of:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServer" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".

How can you use the `TRIM()` function with a linked server connection between postgresql and SQL Server?

Comment: What datatype is alphadawg.userid ? Sounds numeric to me

Comment: Datatype is character(8) - contains alpha-numeric values

Comment: IMHO you have to double the single quotes within the query string: `Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
              'Select TRIM(trailing '' '' from ad.userid) As "User ID"
              FROM alphadawg ad')`. But if you want to remove spaces there's no need to specifiy it at all as it's the default: `TRIM(trailing from ad.userid)`

Comment: Same OLE DB error as above.  Requested conversion is not supported.

Comment: Did you try adding a cast? `CAST(TRIM(trailing from ad.userid) AS VARCHAR(8))`? Btw, PostgreSQL supports `TRIM/RTRIM/LTRIM/BTRIM`

Comment: @dnoeth - your syntax is the only one that has worked for me.  If you post as answer I will accept.

Comment: @spaghettidba was on the right track, too :-)  The `text` datatype caused the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes must be escaped in the `OPENQUERY` argument.

[The return type for the `TRIM` function is `text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html), so you should cast it back to varchar.

```
Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
    'Select CAST(TRIM(trailing '' '' from ad.userid) AS varchar(8)) As "User ID"
    FROM alphadawg ad')
```

Comment: This returns an error of requested conversion is not supported.

Comment: It must be a unicode conversion issue. Trim returns text, which is unicode. Is the linked server declared as collation compatible? See edited answer

Comment: Edited syntax produces error of ERROR: syntax error at or near "varchar";

Comment: Now it should work. I have no Postgresql around to test.

Answer (score 0):

```
You might need to use SQL Server syntax on this one.

Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
'SELECT RTRIM(ad.UserId) AS [User ID]'
 FROM alphadawg AS [ad])
```

OR

```
Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
'SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(ad.UserId),' ','') AS [User ID]'
 FROM alphadawg AS [ad])
```

Comment: The 2nd option you listed produces an error of Incorrect syntax near ',') AS [User ID]'.

Comment: `OPENQUERY` executes the query on the remote server using syntax of the remote system, so this must be PostgreSQL and not T-SQL.

Comment: Good call, @dnoeth I actually thought the remote server was the SQL Server one.

Comment: `OPENQUERY` doesn't exist in PostegreSQL :)

Comment: haha I guess I should have taken that hint initially :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a testing environment but I would be surprised if the following didn't work...

```
Select RTRIM([User ID]) [User ID]  from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
          'Select ad.userid As "User ID"
          FROM alphadawg ad')
```

Comment: I like this one.  Return it as normal from SQL Server, and handle the trimming on the Postgresql side.

Comment: I get an error of 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @user2676140: Of course you have to use `RTRIM`,  it's on the SQL Server side.

Answer (score 0):

OPENQUERY executes given query at remote server to retrieve requested data. So you can at SQL Server if you want as well as at PostgreSQL.

To trim at PostgreSQL, your syntax is incorrect. It should be.

```
Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
              'Select TRIM(ad.userid) As [User ID]
              FROM alphadawg ad')
```

To trim at SQL Server, TRIM is divided into LTRIM (Left Trim) and RTRIM (Right Trim). So you should use bellow query

```
Select RTRIM(LTRIM([User ID])) from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
              'Select ad.userid As [User ID]
              FROM alphadawg ad')
```

Thanks